# How to detect a click event from anywhere in html including iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

In my sample work, I would like to detect the click event from anywhere of my html element. It works when I click on direct `html` but not for `iFrames` - so I would like to hear from any where of my `window`. What is the correct way to do that using `jQuery` ?

**Even I would like to hear from dynamic htmls too. (my case there is a loop with numbers**

[here is the demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1QgOJa1zTWV6xysAS6VQ?p=preview)

my code :

```js
var findAllClicks = function() {
  $(document).on('click', '*', function() {
    console.log($(this)[0]); //only works on direct html element.
  })
}

var outsideFunction = function() {
  console.log('loop ends');
}

outsideFunction();

$(function() {
  //finding click events from any where.
  findAllClicks();
  var total = 1000;
  var i = 0;
  var iterate = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var place = $('#iFrame1').contents().find('#iFrame2').contents().find('body');
      place.append('<ul class="list"></ul>');
      for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        place.find('.list').append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
      }
    }, 3000);
    //how to find all this done from outside of this function?
  }

  var iFrame1 = $('<iframe />', {
    id: 'iFrame1'
  });

  var iFrame2 = $('<iframe />', {
    id: 'iFrame2'
  });

  var button2 = $('<button />', {
    text: 'Child Button',
    click: iterate
  });

  var button = $('<button />', {
    text: 'Click Me',
    click: function() {
      $(this).parents('body').append(iFrame2);
      $('#iFrame1').contents().find('#iFrame2').contents().find('body').append(button2);
    }
  });


  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.container').append(iFrame1);
    $('#iFrame1').contents().find('body').append(button);
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood but if you just wanna log the number of clicks on the window, you could use

```
window.onclick = function() {count++;console.log(count);};
```